# Concur Create User returns 404 Batch element missing

Tags: c#, api, sap-concur

I am trying to create a User in Concur. I referred to [this post](https://forum.developer.concur.com/t/creating-users-what-is-the-correct-users-batch-data-structure/95) to get the Xml format.

Here is the http POST request (Using POSTMAN),

**Request**

```
POST https://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/v1.0/users HTTP/1.1
Authorization: OAuth 0_xxxxxxxtoF3bsxxxBrNwzxxxx=
Accept: application/xml
Content-Type: application/xml; charset=utf-8
Host: www.concursolutions.com
Content-Length: 227
Expect: 100-continue

<Batch xmlns='http://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/2011/02'><UserProfile><EmpId>E0005</EmpId><FeedRecordNumber>1</FeedRecordNumber><LoginId>myuser1@mycompany.com</LoginId><Password>myP@@sword</Password></UserProfile></Batch>
```

**Response**

```
000000B2 <Error><Message>batch element is missing. Please check your
request.</Message><Server-Time>2016-03-28T19:34:02</Server-Time><Id>XXXXXXXX-AACE-4A49-8EE6-669EF3XXXXX</Id></Error>
00000000
```

Why it's complaining that "Batch" element is missing, but clearly it's in the content? Is there any official document I can refer to get the XML format to create Users?

Note: I have tagged C# in this as I am trying get my C# code to work for this. I have written the code to generate the above Request and getting the same response.

NOTE: In the reference post, the `<EmpId>` tag is not closed. When I first tried I got an error saying "The Request XML is invalid.: The 'EmpId' start tag on line 1 position 242 does not match the end tag of 'UserProfile'. Line 1, position 328.". So I corrected that error in my XML. Then I am getting the batch element missing error. Therefore I don't completely trust that XML structure.

Comment: You are missing quite a few fields in your xml compared to the example given in your link. For example, `Active`, `EmailAddress`, `FirstName` and `LastName`. It's saying (from my point of view) that an element of `Batch` is missing. Most likely one of the above fields. You should test it with a *known working* input (ie the example given) first. I'd also be hesitant to keep this `C#` code, because although *your code* is in C#, it has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Hi Rob, that's how I started this. I tried with that first, it's giving the same error. Then I simplified the content only with Required fields, still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try using `"` instead of `'` for your batch namespace attribute?

Comment: I tried that already, same result. Thanks Rob.

Comment: Also I tried adding 2 user profiles as per in the original reference to Concur Post. Still getting the same result. FYI: In the reference post the <EmpId> tag is not closed. I got that error first "EmpId tag closing tag not found...". Therefore I don't completely trust that XML structure in the forum post.

Comment: Have you had a look here? https://developer.concur.com/api-reference/user/company-notification-subscription-resource/user.html - Your request seems fine, all required fields are filled. I haven't been able to find any documentation around `Batch` (apart from saying you need to use a batch element). Perhaps the batch element requires another field. You might have to lodge this as a ticket with concur themselves

Comment: Also I noticed your `Content-Length` is only `224` while there are 227 characters. Since it's `UTF-8`, it should be *at least* 227 bytes long. Perhaps their server is cutting off the closing `Batch` tag and not properly parsing the request?

Comment: Interesting, I will wait for their response. Appreciate your help Rob.

Comment: No worries :) I'm assuming upping the content-length didn't fix it?

Comment: No, I added few more fields (Firstname, lastname), still the same error.

Comment: Yep - But it's likely (long shot) that the server is only reading `224` bytes from the request, and cutting the rest. This would result in malformed XML (and appear to have no `Batch` element). Try forcibly setting your `Content-Length` to the number of characters in your XML.

Comment: I have to mention one thing, when I post this question I changed the Password and loginId, so the contentlength is what I got for the original content 224 which was correct. Now I changed content-length to 227 for the displayed XML data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer from [Concur Developer forum](https://forum.developer.concur.com/t/concur-create-user-returns-404-batch-element-missing/280). Issue is that it's expecting "batch" element which is case sensitive. That's not the only issue in the XML format I mentioned.

This is a working XML Schema for adding users in V3,

```
<batch xmlns="http://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/2011/02" 
xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<UserProfile xmlns="http://www.concursolutions.com/api/user/2011/02" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<FeedRecordNumber>1</FeedRecordNumber>
<Active>Y</Active>
<LoginId>FirstLast@contoso.com</LoginId>
<FirstName>First</FirstName>
<LastName>Last</LastName>
<CtryCode>US</CtryCode>
<LocaleName>en_US</LocaleName>
<CrnKey>USD</CrnKey>
<EmpId>0001</EmpId>
<EmailAddress>FirstLast@contoso.com</EmailAddress>
<Password>password</Password>
<IsTestEmp>N</IsTestEmp>
<ExpenseApprover>Y</ExpenseApprover>
<Custom21>US</Custom21>
<ExpenseUser>Y</ExpenseUser>
<InvoiceApprover>N</InvoiceApprover>
<InvoiceUser>N</InvoiceUser>
<LedgerName>DEFAULT</LedgerName>
<LedgerCode></LedgerCode>
<LocalName>en_US</LocalName>
</UserProfile>
</batch>
```